# She had rented the flat some fourteen months previously. (meaning)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> She had rented the flat some fourteen months previously.

Does it mean that she finished renting that flat 14 months ago, right? (**not** started to rent it 14 months ago)

Comment: That sounds right to me!

Comment: Where did you get this example from? Specifically, did you just make it up for the purpose of asking whether it *would* refer to her prior tenancy starting or ending? The only context in which I would find the cited text idiomatic is if she works in property rentals herself - she rented the flat ***to a customer*** 14 months ago (perhaps that tenant is still there, or perhaps one of her co-workers has rented the same flat out to another customer since then).

Comment: (If *she herself* was the tenant, I'd expect *She'd **been renting** the flat **until** 14 months earlier*, or similar.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/previously (She had rented the flat from the council some fourteen months previously.) Do you think it is an unusual sentence?

Comment: To this US English speaker, it sounds like it means "She *started* to rent the flat 14 months before."  *Renting* doesn't necessary refer to the whole time period that something is rented for; it can also refer to the making of the rental agreement, like "I rented a bicycle and spent the rest of the day exploring town."

Comment: Likewise to this British English speaker. The sentence doesn't strike me as at all unusual and I would understand it the same way as @stangdon

Comment: Obviously I think it's "peculiar" - *if she's not an estate agent*. If she had been a tenant until that time, I'd expect that to be reflected by either/both highlighted amendments: *She had **been renting** the flat **until*** some fourteen months previously*. If she'd ***started*** her tenancy then, I'd expect that to be explicitly stated somehow or other. For example: *She had **been renting** the flat **since** some fourteen months previously.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but to my mind this is entirely dependant on further context - it could just as easily mean that "She" had started to rent the flat, or had finished renting the flat.

It could just as easily refer to her living in the flat, as to renting it to someone else.

We can strongly infer that there was a change of some sort 14 months ago, but even that is not entirely certain - it could theoretically be a comparison with something unrelated, and simply mean that that flat was where she was living, when a particular event occurred.

Comment: My thoughts exactly!